# How to use .db file in django for getting data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a .db file from sqLite3.I want to use it in django project. With inspectdb, I created model from this db file. But I want to get data from this .db file. Is that possible ? And how can I retrieve data from db file ? Thanks.

Inspectdb only create model.py ,not retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

1. create the Django project.
2. Make migrations with similar schema
3. replace the new DB file with this one.

Comment: Existing db is formatted like db.sqlite3 but my db is database.db formatted.Is it still work ? And this is not clear to do.

Comment: It should work...I have done with dB.sqlite3 file before.